# Which is the difference between these two ways to define an attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I was trying to learn about attached properties and I have seen different ways to define an attached properies.

First option:

```
public class PeakHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPeakProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsPeak", typeof (bool), typeof (PeakHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    public static void SetIsPeak(DependencyObject target, Boolean value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsPeakProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsPeak(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (bool)target.GetValue(IsPeakProperty);
    }
}
```

A second option:

```
public static class ThemeProperties
    {
        public static Brush GetTickBrush(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Brush)obj.GetValue(TickBrushProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTickBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TickBrushProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TickBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "TickBrush",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(ThemeProperties),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));
    }
```

In the first case, the class is not static and it inherits from DependencyObject. The second option is a static class and it doesn't inherit from DependencyObject.

Which is the difference? is one better than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview#how-to-create-an-attached-property-): *"If your class is defining the attached property strictly for use on other types, then the class does not have to derive from DependencyObject."*

Comment: @Sinatr You're correct, you should post that as the answer.

Comment: The decision has nothing to do with the declaration of an attached property, but soleley depends on whether you need to create instances of the class or not. Deriving from DependencyObject is not necessary for declaring an attached property, but obviously necessary when there are other (non-attached) dependency properties, which are supposed to be set on instances of the derived class.